# SQL Server - Convert all subqueries to joins

Tags: sql-server

I have below query which has multiple nested subqueries.
The requirement is to convert all the nested subqueries into joins with main outer select query.

```
select * from t1
    where not exists (
      select 1 from t2
      join t21 on t21.c = t2.c
      where t2.y = t1.y 
      and t2.x in (
          select top 1 x from t3
          join t31 on t31.d = t3.d
          where t3.z = t2.z
          and t3.a = t1.a
          order by t3.b
          )
     )
```

Can anyone please help me achieve this?

Comment: Why? Sometime exists can perform better than a join.

Comment: Interesting that the innermost query has a `Top 1` with an `IN` on the outside of it. But your second sentence `requirement` sounds like homework.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I know not exists will be better than a join. But it is the requirement to convert to joins, there are multiple other db sources for which the query is translated with some custom logic where not exists doesnt work very well, and this is the only place i am supposed to make a fix unfortunately